# How to retain first search data when second search is performed

Tags: java, struts, spring-jdbc

I need the implementation logic, where mine logic is failing. Let me explain the functionality.

a) There are two searches in screen , SearchA and SearchB . When i perform SearchA it gives me some result and i display on the screen. 
b) When i perform the SearchB, application will search the data and display on the screen.

**Expected Result** :

```
When SearchB is performed both the search results should be show on the application.
```

**Present Result**:

```
When searchB is performed the search result of SearchA is disappearing and only SearchB is displaying. Visa Versa
```

Please dnt suggest to place the search result in session. Its a huge data (Millions of records) . So please suggest any other apt implementation.

Comment: Might be possible to have each search in its own frame and only update the frame being searched.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that both search, results in page to be reloaded and search result being request scope, the first response gets wiped off on searching the second time (SearchB)

You could paint the result portion of the page using Ajax instead of full page refresh, thereby retaining the search results.

Say you have 2 div SearchAResults and SearchBResults. SearchA will perform ajax request and populate the SearchAResults div once it gets results from server. There is no page load at this time. Similarly, SearchB will just paint the SearchBResults.

Also, if memory(and not design) is the only criteria stopping you from storing result in session, and the search results need to be reused - you could look into some external cache solutions like Memcached whereby there would be dedicated servers just to handle these humongous data.

Comment: Gud Suggestion, but Iam not using ajax in our application. Even iam not sure client accepts ajax calls.

Comment: If not for ajax, and if search results cannot be stored anywhere in server (session, external cache etc) , you would have to go for hacky solution like storing the "search term" in session and on every search pull result for both searches. It solves your problem but definitely not good design or practice. I think you need to revisit your designs/architecture.